# adding style html js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Look at my screenshot below. If I remove this property the chat will not open. I tried with CSS to remove it and then use jquery/js to add it back, but it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem? That the "div" in closed format would not cover my background

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUde2.png)

I want it to be closed before it opens

```js
function chatInit(selector) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    if (!window.LIVE_CHAT_UI) {
      let chat = document.querySelector(selector);
      let toggles = chat.querySelectorAll('.toggle')
      let close = chat.querySelector('.close')
      
      toggles.forEach( toggle => {
        toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
          chat.classList.add('is-active')
        })
      })
      close.addEventListener('click', () => {
        chat.classList.remove('is-active')
      })    
      
      window.LIVE_CHAT_UI = true
    }
  })
}

chatInit('#chat-app')
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chat-app {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  height: 600px;
  width: 360px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  color: #141E30;
}
.chat-app .title {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
}
.chat-app .subtitle {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
}

.chat-app:not(.is-active) .chat-app_toggle:hover {
  -webkit-animation: 0.5s blob linear;
          animation: 0.5s blob linear;
}

.chat-app_toggle {
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.75em;
  right: 0.75em;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  transform: scale(0.83);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00c6ff, #0072ff);
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 198, 255, 0.4);
}
.chat-app_toggle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: none;
}
.chat-app_toggle .icon {
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.72, 0.17, 0.36, 1.03) 0.4s;
}
.chat-app_toggle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #00c6ff;
  opacity: 0;
}
.chat-app_toggle:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00cdac, #00ae92);
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.chat-app_box {
  border-radius: 16px 16px 40px 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: white;
}

.chat-app_header {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00c6ff, #0072ff);
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.chat-app_header .branding {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.5em 1.5em;
}
.chat-app_header .close {
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  background: #141e30;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.chat-app_header .close:after, .chat-app_header .close:before {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.25em;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  background: white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.chat-app_header .close:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.chat-app_header .close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: 1;
}
.chat-app_header .avatar {
  margin-right: 1em;
  position: relative;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
.chat-app_header .avatar img {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(20, 30, 48, 0.2);
}
.chat-app_header .avatar.is-online:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0.75em;
  width: 0.75em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.2em;
  right: 0.2em;
  background: #00cdac;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white;
}
.chat-app_header .content {
  width: calc(100% - 48px - 1em);
}

.chat-app_content {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 1em);
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}
.chat-app_content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5em;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.chat-app_content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ededed;
}
.chat-app_content .messages {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
  position: absolute;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
.chat-app_content .message {
  width: calc(100% - 2em);
  padding: 0 0.75em 0 0.75em; /* Haut droite bas gauche */
  background: white;
  margin-top: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-left: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00c6ff, #0072ff);
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  word-break: break-word;;
}
.chat-app_content .message:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0.75em;
  right: -1em;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 75% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 75% 100%);
  background: #0072ff;
  transform: skewY(15deg);
}
.chat-app_content .message.reply {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 2em;
  background: #ededed;
  color: #141E30;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.chat-app_content .message.reply:after {
  right: unset;
  left: -1em;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 25% 100%, 100% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 25% 100%, 100% 100%);
  background: #ededed;
  transform: skewY(-15deg);
}

.chat-app_footer {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 0.75em;
  position: relative;
}
.chat-app_footer .tools {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}
.chat-app_footer .tools .copyright {
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: right;
}
.chat-app_footer .tools .button-icon {
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  background: white;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  color: #a0a0a0;
  position: relative;
}
.chat-app_footer .tools .button-icon i {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.chat-app_footer .tools .button-icon:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00c6ff, #0072ff);
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.chat-app_footer .tools .button-icon:hover, .chat-app_footer .tools .button-icon:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 198, 255, 0.4);
  color: white;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.chat-app_footer .tools .button-icon:hover:after, .chat-app_footer .tools .button-icon:focus:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.chat-input {
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #ededed;
  border: solid 1px #a0a0a0;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.chat-input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 205, 172, 0.4);
  border-color: #00cdac;
  background: white;
}

.chat-app .chat-app_box {
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.71, 0, 0.23, 1.38) 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(-3deg) scale(0.8);
}
.chat-app .chat-app_header .avatar {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.6);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.chat-app .chat-app_header .content {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.chat-app .icon.send {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%) scale(0.5);
}
.chat-app .icon.open {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.chat-app .chat-input {
  transition: all 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.chat-app.is-active .chat-app_box {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: unset;
  transform: none;
}
.chat-app.is-active .chat-app_header .avatar,
.chat-app.is-active .chat-app_header .content {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: none;
}
.chat-app.is-active .icon.send {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.chat-app.is-active .icon.open {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%) scale(0.5);
}
.chat-app.is-active .chat-app_toggle:before {
  -webkit-animation: chat-bubble cubic-bezier(0.15, 0.4, 0.15, 1) 0.7s;
          animation: chat-bubble cubic-bezier(0.15, 0.4, 0.15, 1) 0.7s;
}
.chat-app.is-active .chat-app_toggle:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.chat-app.is-active .chat-input {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .chat-app .chat-app_box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .chat-app .chat-app_toggle {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0.75em;
    right: 0.75em;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes chat-bubble {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.6);
  }
}
@keyframes chat-bubble {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.6);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blob {
  0% {
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
  }
  25% {
    border-radius: 60% 95% 60% 95%;
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 90% 65% 90% 65%;
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 80% 98% 80% 98%;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes blob {
  0% {
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
  }
  25% {
    border-radius: 60% 95% 60% 95%;
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 90% 65% 90% 65%;
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 80% 98% 80% 98%;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500:600|Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.css">


<div id="chat-app" class="chat-app">
  
  <div class="chat-app_toggle toggle">
    <div class="icon send">
      <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="icon open">
      <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="chat-app_box">
    <div class="chat-app_header">
      
      <div class="close"></div>
        
        <div class="content">
          <p class="title">ChatBot</p>
          <p class="subtitle">Ask me anything, I am here to help you.</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this to your css code

```
div#chat-app { height: 0; }
div#chat-app.is-active { height: 600px; }
```

Comment: The widget is gone now

Comment: The widget disappears as I add to it: `display: none;`

Comment: div#chat-app {
    height: 0;
}
div#chat-app.is-active {
    height: 600px;
}